# GMap.NET with own vector map tile server

Tags: c#, winforms, mapbox, gmap.net, vector-tiles

I'm looking for a way to use vector map tiles with Gmap.net so they can be styled and stored offline easily. There's a great project, VectorTileRenderer (https://github.com/AliFlux/VectorTileRenderer) for WinForms, which supports the Mapbox/Openmaptiles vector tile specification. They provide a demo for using an MBTiles file as a GMap.net provider:

```
// load the source
var provider = new VectorMbTilesProvider(@"tiles/zurich.mbtiles", @"styles/basic-style.json", @"tile-cache/");

// attach it to the map
gmap.MapProvider = provider;
```

Is it possible to use a vector tile server, such as the Mapbox Vector Tiles API, as the provider? I'm extremely new to this but I think GMap.net handles retrieving the of the tiles given the URL structure. The one for Mapbox is: `/v4/{tileset_id}/{zoom}/{x}/{y}{@2x}.{format}`. I'm not sure how to use the URL with the VectorTilesRenderer though.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?